# Why do power series converge to a function symmetrically?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

[Why does the taylor series of $\ln (1 + x)$ only approximate it for $-1<x \le 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365516/why-does-the-taylor-series-of-ln-1-x-only-approximate-it-for-1x-le-1)

The selected answer to the above question says that for a a power series, the interval of convergence for the Taylor series is syymetric around $a$, where $a$ is the domain value the power series is centered around.

Could someone provide an intuitive reason as to why this is true? Note I am **not** just looking for a formal proof, I am looking for intuition.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For reasons apparent when considering complex arguments, power series converge inside a _circle_ around the center (that's why they talk about "radius of convergence"). This circle (centered on the real line) gives a range symmetric around it in the reals.

Comment: @vonbrand: you mean, inside a *disk* around the center.

Comment: What's the difference, @xyzzyz?

Comment: @xyzzyz "*Inside a circle*" (on a disk) is correct, while "*inside a disk*" (what is the inside of a disk, if not the disk itself?) is disputable.

Comment: "Inside a circle" can be interpreted as "on a circle". The most unambiguous ways of expressing it is I thing "inside a disk bounded by a circle".

Comment: You're all crazy. Either that or mathematicians.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, tricky one.

The intuition of the formal proof (not sure if this counts!) is that if a series converges conditionally, then it is at worst 'balanced on the edge' of convergence (root test gives 1); hence if you slightly improve convergence by decreasing $|x|$, the series converges 'properly' (root test gives something proportionally less than 1). Hence

> the regions of *conditional* convergence are at most points balanced precariously on a boundary of a region of *absolute* convergence, which obviously must be symmetric.

Thus $(-1,1]$ type intervals are as asymmetric as you can get. This generalizes immediately to the complex plane, where the absolutely convergent region is trivially circular, and the conditionally convergent region is a part of the circle bounding this disc.

Morally, therefore, the symmetric nature ultimately arises from the simple fact that

> the series at $+x$ converges *absolutely* if and only if it does at $-x$

combined with the above observation that conditionally convergent regions are 'narrow', 'unstable', 'borderline cases', etc.