# Why is $\operatorname{Sech}(x)$ Taylor series divergent past $\pi/2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Someone asked a question here about why the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ diverges:

[Why does the taylor series of $\ln (1 + x)$ only approximate it for $-1<x \le 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365516/why-does-the-taylor-series-of-ln-1-x-only-approximate-it-for-1x-le-1)

I have a similar question: why does the $\operatorname{Sech}(x)$ Taylor series diverge at $\pi/2$?

The answer in the $\log$ question dealt with the fact that the only symmetric interval that could be defined for $\log$ is from $-1$ to $1$ as $\log$ is only defined from $(-1, \infty)$. $\operatorname{Sech}(x)$ is defined everywhere and it doesn't have this problem.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The reason is the same as for the Taylor series of $1/(1+x^2)$ that only converges for $-1<x<1$.

Comment: Radius of convergence is answered.  But how about convergence at the point $\pi/2$, which is on the boundary of the region of convergence?

Comment: the major contribution of comples analysis is that there is an equivalence between "a power series, analytic on a disk" and "no singularity on that disk", i.e. $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ always has a singularity on the boundary of its disk of convergence, and conversely, it doesn't converge past its largest singularity-free disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest reason is in complex analysis.  $\mathrm{sech}(x)$ has a pole at $i\pi/2$, so the radius of convergenge cannot extend beyond that point.  And moreover, there are no singularities strictly closer to $0$, so the radius of convergence is exactly $\pi/2$.