# Maclaurin Series Expansion $\ln(8+x^3)$.

Tags: integration

> Find Maclaurin Series Expansion of function $\ln(8+x^3)$. For which $x$ series converges? For which $ x $ ,$ f(x)$ equals sum of this series?

---

$$ (\ln(8+x^3))'=\frac{3x^2}{8+x^3} =\frac{\frac{3}{8}x^2}{1-(-\frac{x^3}{8})}=$$
$$ =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3x^2}{8}(-1)^n\frac{x^{3n}}{8^n}$$
and 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int\frac{3x^2}{8}(-1)^n\frac{x^{3n}}{8^n}dx=$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n3}{8^{n+1}}\int x^{3n+2}dx=$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n3}{8^{n+1}}\frac{x^{3n+3}}{3n+3}+C$$

for $x=0$
$$\ln(8+0^3)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n3}{8^{n+1}}\frac{0^{3n+3}}{3n+3}+C $$
$$ C=0 $$

$8+x^3>0 $

$x>-2 $

and

$|\frac{-x^3}{8}|<1$

$x<2$

> I have to find if it converges only at $x=2$, $x=-2$ is out of domain?  For which $x$ series converges? For which $ x $ ,$ f(x)$ equals sum of this series? From Abel theorem $\forall$ x which converges $f(x)$=sum of series?

Comment: -2 is out. 2 is ok as the series is "alternating". Look up  "alternating series test" in wiki

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\ln(8+x^3)=\ln8+\ln\left(1+\dfrac{x^3}8\right)$$

See [Why does the taylor series of $\ln (1 + x)$ only approximate it for $-1<x \le 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365516/why-does-the-taylor-series-of-ln-1-x-only-approximate-it-for-1x-le-1)

OR

[Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ and its convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594838/taylor-series-for-log1x-and-its-convergence)

OR

[What is the correct radius of convergence for $\ln(1+x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x)

Comment: I understand your way of doing this task. :) Could you please tell me how to finish mine alternative solution? :)